# Provide __classcell__ example for Python 3.6 metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass, python-3.6

Per the 3.6.0 docs:

> **CPython implementation detail**: In CPython 3.6 and later, the `__class__`
>   cell is passed to the metaclass as a `__classcell__` entry in the class
>   namespace. If present, this must be propagated up to the `type.__new__`
>   call in order for the class to be initialized correctly. Failing to do
>   so will result in a `DeprecationWarning` in Python 3.6, and a
>   `RuntimeWarning` in the future.

Can someone provide an example of doing this correctly?

An example where it's actually needed?

Comment: Some ideas: this patch has the right key words (I dunno if this patch made it or not): http://bugs.python.org/file44533/classcell.patch

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The warning is raised if you use super that relies on `__class__` being available or reference `__class__` inside the class body.

What the text essentially says is that, this is needed if you define a custom meta-class and tamper with the namespace you get before passing it up to `type.__new__`. You'll need to be careful and always make sure you pass `__classcell__` to `type.__new__` in your `metaclass.__new__`.

That is, if you create a new fancy namespace to pass up, always check if `__classcell__` is defined in the original namespace created and add it:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        my_fancy_new_namespace = {....}  
        if '__classcell__' in namespace:
             my_fancy_new_namespace['__classcell__'] = namespace['__classcell__']
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, my_fancy_new_namespace)
```

The file you linked in the comment is actually the first of many attempted patches, [`issue23722_classcell_reference_validation_v2.diff`](http://bugs.python.org/file45748/issue23722_classcell_reference_validation_v2.diff) is the final patch that made it in, from [Issue 23722](http://bugs.python.org/issue23722).

An example of doing this correctly can be seen in a [pull request made to Django](https://github.com/django/django/pull/7653/files) that uses this to fix an issue that was introduced in Python 3.6:

```
new_attrs = {'__module__': module}
classcell = attrs.pop('__classcell__', None)
if classcell is not None:
    new_attrs['__classcell__'] = classcell
new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, new_attrs)
```

The `__classcell__` is simply added to the new namespace before being passed to `type.__new__`.

Comment: It took me a while to find out it is created if any method inside the class uses the `super()` form.

This comes likely because before it was impossible to call any classmethod that would make use of `super()` inside the metaclass methods itself. More likely, the new `__init_subclass__` mechansm in Python 3.6 needs it.

Comment: @jsbueno yup, `__init_subclass__` with a custom metaclass, though. If you use `type` you're fine.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard could you provide a reference or a simple example to illustrate custom namespace?