# `super` in a `typing.NamedTuple` subclass fails in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.6, super, python-3.8

I have code which worked in Python 3.6 and fails in Python 3.8. It seems to boil down to calling `super` in subclass of `typing.NamedTuple`, as below:

```py
<ipython-input-2-fea20b0178f3> in <module>
----> 1 class Test(typing.NamedTuple):
      2     a: int
      3     b: float
      4     def __repr__(self):
      5         return super(object, self).__repr__()

RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'Test' as <class '__main__.Test'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

```py
In [3]: class Test(typing.NamedTuple): 
   ...:     a: int 
   ...:     b: float 
   ...:     #def __repr__(self): 
   ...:     #    return super(object, self).__repr__() 
   ...:                                                                         

>>> # works
```

The purpose of this `super(object, self).__repr__` call is to use the standard `'<__main__.Test object at 0x7fa109953cf8>'` `__repr__` instead of printing out all the contents of the tuple elements (which would happen by default). There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55614454/4280242) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41347038/4280242) on `super` resulting in similar errors but they:

1. Refer to the parameter-less version `super()`
2. Fail already in Python 3.6 (it worked for me before 3.6 -> 3.8 upgrade)
3. I fail to understand how to fix this anyway, given that it's not a custom metaclass I have control over but the stdlib-provided `typing.NamedTuple`.

My question is how can I fix this while maintaining backwards compatibility with Python 3.6 (otherwise I'd just use `@dataclasses.dataclass` instead of inheriting from `typing.NamedTuple`)?

A side question is how can this fail *at definition time* given that the offending `super` call is inside a method which is not even executed yet. For instance:

```py
In [3]: class Test(typing.NamedTuple): 
   ...:     a: int 
   ...:     b: float 
   ...:     def __repr__(self): 
   ...:         return foo
```

works (until we actually call the `__repr__`) even though `foo` is an undefined reference. Is `super` magical in that regard?

Comment: When I run your code in Python 3.6, I get a representation of the `super` object itself, not a representation of your `Test` instance.

Comment: Also, it appears that whatever compile-time magic allows for implicit arguments still occurs to do some validation of explicit arguments.

Comment: using `__repr__ = object.__repr__` in your class definition works for me on Python3.6 & Python3.8

Comment: @chepner indeed, now I am starting to get confused about why it worked before. But it did...

Comment: This issue is caused by the metaclass of `typing.NamedTuple`; `typing.NamedTupleMeta`, that's doing some shenanigans. `super()` requires `__class__` to be available *at compile time*, which isn't the case here, apparently. See also: [Provide `__classcell__` example for Python 3.6 metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41343263/1016216)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thanks, that's a good idea. Please go ahead with posting this as a answer, if nobody answers this more in depth soon, I'll accept it.

Comment: I second Azat's suggestion: since `object` is necessarily the final class in any class's MRO, you don't need `super`'s "cooperative" powers.

Comment: `NamedTuple` has a [metaclass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/typing.py#L2131) that limits overloading magic methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was slightly wrong in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41343263/1016216) (which I just updated). 
Apparently, this behavior manifests in *both* cases of `super`. In hindsight, I should have tested this.

What's happening here is the metaclass `NamedTupleMeta` indeed doesn't pass `__classcell__` over to `type.__new__` because it creates a namedtuple on the fly and returns that. Actually, in Python's 3.6 and 3.7 (where this is still a `DeprecationWarning`), the `__classcell__` leaks into the class dictionary since it isn't removed by `NamedTupleMeta.__new__`.

```
class Test(NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: float
    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__()

# isn't removed by NamedTupleMeta
Test.__classcell__
<cell at 0x7f956562f618: type object at 0x5629b8a2a708>
```

Using `object.__repr__` directly as suggested by Azat does the trick.

> how can this fail at definition time

The same way the following also fails:

```
class Foo(metaclass=1): pass
```

*Many* checks are performed while the class is being constructed. Among these, is checking if the metaclass has passed the `__classcell__` over to `type_new`.

Comment: Is this a bug in stdlib then?

Comment: @Jatentaki The leaking of `__classcell__`, I would've thought so. Supporting `super`, don't know, same way as multiple inheritance [recently changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19363) to now raise an error. Might still be worth it to create an issue, though.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I'm not so familiar with CPython internals and classes generation to say why it fails, but there is [this CPython bug tracker issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue23722) which seems to be related and some words in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object)

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython 3.6 and later, the `__class__` cell is passed to the metaclass as a `__classcell__` entry in the class namespace. If present, this must be propagated up to the `type.__new__` call in order for the class to be initialised correctly. Failing to do so will result in a `RuntimeError` in Python 3.8.

so probably somewhere during actual `namedtuple` creation we have a call to `type.__new__` without `__classcell__` propagated, but I don't know if it's the case.

But this particular case seems to be solvable by not using `super()` call with explicitly saying that "we need to have `__repr__` method of the `object` class" like

```py
class Test(typing.NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: float
    __repr__ = object.__repr__
```

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround which seems to work for me at least is the following:

```py
class BaseTest(typing.NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: float
    

class Test(BaseTest):
    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__()
```

By subclassing the NameTuple-based class, it's seems the class cell taken caer of.

Answer (score 0):

FOllowing: https://bugs.python.org/issue42765?

This trick (not using super()) saved me:
return tuple.**getitem**(self, index_or_key)