# How to define an initializer in a PyMODM model class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, pymodm

I would like to have a custom initializer for my PyMODM class. Doing it the straightforward way

```
class MyModel(MongoModel):
    fields = ...
    def __init__(self, other_args...):
        super().__init__(other_args)
        do_something_else()
```

produces first a warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: __class__ not set defining 'MyModel' as <class '__main__.MyModel'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

and then an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing required positional arguments
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
class MyModel(MongoModel):
fields = ...
def __init__(self, other_args...):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(other_args)
    do_something_else()
```

Works, but i get `DeprecationWarning: __class__ not set defining...`

Here [Provide __classcell__ example for Python 3.6 metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343263/provide-classcell-example-for-python-3-6-metaclass) they explain more, but I do not understand it at all

Comment: It doesn't work when you try to retrieve something from the database. I can't add `__classcell__` directly into the `type.__init__` call in the metaclass because that metaclass is part of the library.